# Cut feature from the same layer with the buffer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, layers, buffer, clip, features

Is it possible in QGIS to cut with a buffer a feature from the **same** layer, like it is in the editing mode for ArcGIS (see picture below)?

[image: Example of editing option in ArcGIS]

Answer (score 1):

**To clarify per @mgri comment.

As far as I'm aware, no it isn't possible with a one-step approach via any current QGIS tools or plugins. The documentation that I'm aware doesn't make mention of that being possible in any of the tools related to spatial queries, buffering or/and clipping.

[Vector Spatial Analysis (Buffers)](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/gentle_gis_introduction/vector_spatial_analysis_buffers.html)

[Spatial Query Plugin](https://docs.qgis.org/2.2/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/plugins_spatial_query.html)

Comment: I think it is not possible with a one-step approach, but it is surely doable by combining the built-in selection and spatial analysis tools.